# How Sonata Admin Bundle in the left main menu to add custom page (NO CRUD! and not to the dashboard!)

Tags: php, menu, sonata-admin

How Sonata Admin Bundle in the left main menu to add custom page?

NO CRUD! 
NOT to the dashboard!

Separate independent page, example: statistic, or help, or simaple html page or custom route page.

Thanks!

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb2Gd.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to overload blocks in `SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig`. The ones you are looking for are **side_bar_before_nav** and **side_bar_after_nav**. In this case you can add link before/after menu, not in the middle.

For example:

Create file `standard_layout.html` in your `src/yourbundle/Resources/views`

```
{% extends "SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig" %}
{% block side_bar_before_nav %}
    <a href="#">Test</a>
{% endblock %}
```

add some css classes to properly format the link as you wish.

You should have got config file in `app/Resources/config` (config.yml or your own) with sonata config options, add there name of your default layout

```
sonata_admin:
    title:      Admin Panel
    templates:
        layout: YourOwnBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
```

After this you have to clear your cache

```
$ php app/console cache:clear
```

Another approach is to create it as admin class with your own controller. Then you can remove all routes and add your own and create your own action.

Comment: Thanks this work!  The side_bar_before_nav into my own (custom) knp_menu with "menu Builder" is the way to go. 
**The Sonata own menu can not be extended**.